# How to disable i element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Why can't `i` element is not getting disabled. I want to make it unclickable when i click on disable button

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lax4u/mvzu1o75/)

**Html**

```
<i class="foo">Click Me to see if i am disabled.</i>

<button type="button" id="btn">
   Disable
</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(".foo").click(function(){
  var isDisabled =  $(".foo").is(":disabled");
    alert("Is foo disabled: " + isDisabled);
})

$("#btn").click(function(){
  $(".foo").css("color","red");
    $(".foo").prop("disabled",true);

})
```

Comment: <i> is not an element that can be disabled. You should not treat an "icon" as a button by itsself.

Comment: I am using font-awesome as `<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>` and i wanted to disable it

Comment: Yes I know, but an <i> element is not something you disable. It is not an interactive element.

Answer (score 1):

`<i>` elements aren't buttons; giving them a `disabled` property doesn't do anything.

If you want to do something like this, either make it into a button instead, or toggle a class on it to indicate whether it's clickable or not.

```js
$(".foo").click(function(){
  var isDisabled =  $(".foo").is(":disabled");
    alert("Is foo disabled: " + isDisabled);
})

$("#btn").click(function(){
  $(".foo").css("color","red");
    $(".foo").prop("disabled",true);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="foo">Click Me to see if i am disabled.</button>

<button type="button" id="btn">
   Disable
</button>
```

or

```js
$(".foo").click(function() {
  var isDisabled = $(this).is(".disabled");
  alert("Is foo disabled: " + isDisabled);
})

$("#btn").click(function() {
  $(".foo").css("color", "red");
  $(".foo").toggleClass("disabled");

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="foo">Click Me to see if i am disabled.</i>

<button type="button" id="btn">
   Disable
</button>
```

Comment: Or add an attribute that indicates whether it is enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the i is disabled before alerting the message.
Using `if(isDisabled) return;`
Add this line after declaring isDisabled in the click event handler for tag element. excuse me for not formatting ly response i am only using my phone right now.

Just replace your first part of code with this:

```
$(".foo").click(function(){
  var isDisabled =  $(".foo").is(":disabled");
    If(isDisabled) return; // exit function
    alert("Is foo disabled: " + isDisabled);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".foo").click(function(){
  var isDisabled =  $(".foo").prop("disabled");
  alert("you clicked foo " + isDisabled);
})

$("#btn").click(function(){
  $(".foo").off('click');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.foo').css('pointer-events','none');
```

Or just apply class like this:

CSS:

```
.disabledClass{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.foo').addClass('disabledClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

With css:

```
$("i"+the_id).css("pointer-events","none");
//or
$("i").css("pointer-events","none");
```